# R export to SPSS file, with variable names longer than 8 characters

Tags: r, export, spss

I'm using R and have tried the foreign package, but cannot find a way to export R data frame into SPSS formats (e.g. sps) where the variable names are longer than 8 characters.   No, i don't not wish to shrink the variable names, as I will incur many duplicates.

Does anyone know how to cleanly export R data frames into SPSS formats without change the data (e.g. shortening variable names)?

I am not looking for a work-around solution (i.e. manual coding), but searching for the existence of a package solution that improves up that of foreign.

thank you.

Comment: can spss not read csv or any other plain text file format?

Comment: it can, but that's an extra step in a cross-team automation that I would rather not deal with, and doesn't really address the fundamental issue of R not being able to save to other formats (e.g. SPSS).

Comment: Have a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10181730/1305688)

Comment: that is a very helpful link.  I wouldn't claim this answer is solved yet, but I think I can use that link as a work around. thank you eric.

Comment: this question has not been answered, "information from `label attribute` in R to `VARIABLE LABELS` in SPSS 2" does not answer the question. that answer provides a work-around. I am looking for a package solution and it is very possible that someone has built the correct package. Richard, you are inhibiting the development/exploration of this problem by marking as duplicate.